# $a,x,y,z,b$ are in arithmetic progression, and separately in harmonic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $a,b$ be positive integers. The values of $xyz$ are $55$ and $\frac{343}{55}$ when $a,x,y,z,b$ are in arithmetic progression and harmonic progression, respectively. Find the value of $a+b.$

When $a,x,y,z,b$ are in arithmetic progression, $$x=\frac{3a+b}{4},y=\frac{2b+2a}{4},z=\frac{a+3b}{4}.$$ When $a,x,y,z,b$ are in harmonic progression, $$x=\frac{4ab}{a+3b},y=\frac{4ab}{2a+2b},z=\frac{4ab}{b+3a}.$$
These equations give $ab=7.$

The answer is that $a+b=8.$ But how do I determine this?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and their product is 7, a prime number. Is there any other posibility except $a=1$ and $b=7$.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly the bounty is trying to accomplish: fill in the algebra or prove $ab=7 \implies a + b = 8$?  Or something else perhaps? What would be a canonical answer in this context?

Answer (score 1):

You've already got $ab=7$ correctly. As pointed out in a comment, note that $7$ is a prime number. Since $a,b$ are positive integers, it is necessary that $(a,b)=(1,7),(7,1)$.

I'm going to write two more solutions:

---

**Solution 1** :

We may suppose that $a\le b$.

Let $d$ be the common difference of arithmetic progression $a,x,y,z,b$.

Let $D$ be the common difference of arithmetic progression $\frac 1a,\frac 1X,\frac 1Y,\frac 1Z,\frac 1b$.

Since we have $d=\frac{b-a}{4}$ and $D=\frac{a-b}{4ab}$, we get
$$abD=-d$$

Using this, we get
$$\begin{align}xyzXYZ&=(a+d)(b-2d)(b-d)\times\frac{1}{(\frac 1a+D)(\frac 1a+2D)(\frac 1b-D)}
\\\\&=\frac{a+d}{\frac 1b-D}\times\frac{b-2d}{\frac 1a+2D}\times\frac{b-d}{\frac 1a+D}
\\\\&=\frac{ab(a+d)}{a-abD}\times\frac{ab(b-2d)}{b+2abD}\times\frac{ab(b-d)}{b+abD}
\\\\&=\frac{ab(a+d)}{a+d}\times\frac{ab(b-2d)}{b-2d}\times\frac{ab(b-d)}{b-d}
\\\\&=(ab)^3\end{align}$$

Since $a,b$ are positive integers, we get
$$55\times\frac{7^3}{55}=(ab)^3\implies ab=7\implies (a,b)=(1,7)$$

$(a,b)=(1,7)$ is sufficient since $1,\frac 52,4,\frac{11}{2},7$ and $1,\frac{14}{11},\frac{7}{4},\frac{14}{5},7$ satisfy the condition.

Therefore, the value of $a+b$ is $\color{red}8$.

---

**Solution 2** :

We may suppose that $a\le b$.

If $a,x,y,z,b$ are in arithmetic progression, then by AM-GM inequality, we get

$$y=\frac{x+z}{2}\ge \sqrt{xz}\implies y^3\ge xyz=55\implies y\gt 3.5$$

$$a+b=2y\gt 7\implies a+b\ge 8\tag1$$

If $a,X,Y,Z,b$ are in harmonic progression, then by AM-GM inequality, we get
$$Y=\bigg(\frac{\frac 1X+\frac 1Z}{2}\bigg)^{-1}\le \sqrt{XZ}\implies Y^3\le XYZ=\frac{343}{55}\lt 8\implies Y\lt 2$$
$$\frac 1a+\frac 1b=\frac 2Y\gt 1$$
Suppose that $a\ge 2$. Then, $\frac 1a+\frac 1b\le \frac 12+\frac 12=1$, a contradiction. So, $a=1$.

Suppose that $b\ge 8$. Then, the common difference $d$ of arithmetic progression $a,x,y,z,b$ satisfies  $d=\frac{b-a}{4}\ge \frac{8-1}{4}\gt 1.5$, so this implies

$$55=xyz\gt (1+1.5)(1+2\times 1.5)(1+3\times 1.5)=55$$
This is a contradiction. So, $b\le 7$. From $(1)$, we get $b=7$.

$(a,b)=(1,7)$ is sufficient since $1,\frac 52,4,\frac{11}{2},7$ and $1,\frac{14}{11},\frac{7}{4},\frac{14}{5},7$ satisfy the condition.

Therefore, the value of $a+b$ is $\color{red}8$.